# .htaccess limit IP range

Tags: .htaccess, ip, limit

I have a *.htaccess* file that limits the access of my website to an IP range.
I do it like that :

```
# Limite access to 160.98.xxx.xxx
<Limit GET POST>
    order deny,allow
    deny from all
    allow from 160.98.
</Limit>
```

But I have a "**Forbidden** You don't have permission to access /testip/test.txt on this server." when I tried to access it with my IP that actually begins with 160.98.

Am I doing it something wrong with the *.htaccess* ? It is located to the root of the website. I have generated the code of the *.htaccess* with http://www.toshop.com/htaccess-generator.cfm

Comment: Sure that file is interpreted? You have to enable usage of `.htaccess` style files.

Comment: And a side node: _if_ you have access to the real server configuration then prefer such configurations there over `.htaccess` style files. Those files make things more complex, are error prone, hard to debug and make the server slooooooow!

Comment: @arkascha
Yes, the .htaccess is enable on the Apache (if a remove it, I can access the website).

Comment: Hm, the syntax looks fine to me. You _did_ check that this _really_ is the request address you contact the server with? Check the log files!

Comment: I have this line on my Apache logs file : `127.0.0.1 - - [10/Apr/2014:11:38:14 +0200] "GET /testip/test.txt HTTP/1.1" 403 217`

Comment: See? You are _not_ requesting from the address you permit. You have to add your local address: 127.0.0.1! See my answer based on this below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your comment above you request with a local address, not with the one you expected. So you have to grant access to that address to:

```
# Limite access to 160.98.xxx.xxx
<Limit GET POST>
    order deny,allow
    deny from all
    allow from 160.98.
    allow from 127.0.
</Limit>
```

Most likely that is not your ultimate goal, but it answers the question. If you want to test if the specified address range starting with `160.98.` has access, then you have to make a request from such an address. Currently you don't, since obviously you test from the same system which will always use the loopback address.

Comment: Damn you're right! I didn't even thought of that. Thanks a lot !

Comment: Maybe this works but the proper notation for IP ranges is `allow from 160.98.0.0/16`.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the last `.` should fix it.

```
# Limite access to 160.98.xxx.xxx
<Limit GET POST>
    order deny,allow
    deny from all
    allow from 160.98
</Limit>
```

Comment: No, I still have a **forbidden**

Comment: Try hard refresh the page/try a different browser.

Answer (score 0):

im no expert but doesn't having the 'deny from all' conflict with what your doing,
shouldn't you only be listing the allow from in their?  i'd expect their might be some kind of exept command to go along with the deny all,
, 
plus shouldn't you be listing the full 127.0.0.1 instead of just 127.0. wouldn't this confuse it? like i say im no expert but that was my first thought when looking.

Im still trying to figure out if i can use a * symbol after the . in an IP to block any number after the dot.  I want to block IP ranges and would have liked to have just put a - sign between the range but from what im reading on this site i have to do it some other way. im still reading for the answer! i want to stick a block list from a site lick spamhaus to block all baddies!